# jQuery Mouse Flicker in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, flicker, mouse-cursor

When I execute a jQuery function like .fadeIn, .fadeOut, .slideUp, .slideDown, .toggle, etc. in IE the mouse always flickers and the hourglass quickly flickers in and out of view next to the cursor.  I've tried different methods of hiding the mouse entirely while the animation is going on to no avail, plus I don't want that in most cases anyways.

Does anyone have another solution to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing animation on anything that has a CSS defined background image, IE will do this.  If you can do that in another way (`<img>` tag, exclude that element when IE animates, etc) it should eliminate the flicker.

Comment: IIRC, setting a background color on the element will also fix it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what to do?

Comment: Is this still a known issue in IE11? Is there most details anywhere? Its very hard to google due to keywors overlapping with other pc issues yet I seem to have this problem with a site I am developing. Constant flickering hourglass.

Comment: I have tried all off them but the problem is still same in IE 11. I have Used slideToggle function for accordion.