# Navigation bar Flickers Only in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer

I've been trying to debugg this for hours now with **no success.**  I blieve i boiled it down to the background slider which is SUPERSIZED.js.  Unfortunately their forum lacked support also.

If someone fires up **IE9** and goes to *http://www.designobvio.us/avproduktor/*
you'll see that everytime you move the mouse across the screen the first two `LI` (home & news) flicker with the mouse movement.

I've google'd this problem for hours does anyone have any incite?

> [jQuery Mouse Flicker in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372079/jquery-mouse-flicker-in-ie)

I believe that this is a similar issue however, my menus must be bi-lingual therefore this fix will not work?

I'll gladly provide full package for anyone if you can help!
Thank you so much for your time,
Matthew

Comment: IE `eats` one core of my portable notebook. It is not a netbook, but light and portable. Even my js script moving text along the curve letter by letter did not eat so much. It basically shows that the script is not well optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to your problem is to set some high z-index in css style of these elements. I tried it in developer tools of IE and it helped (I've added it manually to the style of LI elements  in the menu). Let say

```
.menu-item {z-index: 10000;}
```